# now() function is not working with valueBlobFile in liquibase

Tags: liquibase

When insert data in mysql using liquibase insert tag like

```
    <insert tableName="image">
        <column name="body" valueBlobFile="image/logo.png" />
        <column name="createddt" valueDate="now()"/>           
        <column name="updateddt" valueDate="now()" />                     
    </insert>
```

NULL is inserted in createddt and updateddt column. But if use same code without valueBlobFile, date is inserted properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mysql you can use the following:

```
<insert tableName="image">
    <column name="body" value="LOAD_FILE(image/logo.png)" />
    <column name="createddt" value="now()"/>
    <column name="updateddt" value="now()" />
</insert>
```